# Apple Music - How to automatically save everything that it added to My Music?

Tags: apple-music

I would like to know if there's a way in which every time I add a song or album into "My Music", it is saved in the device automatically, without selecting the option "Save for Offline".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres no way to do that as of now, maybe that feature will be added later though. You can automatically download all of the songs in a specific playlist though.

Comment: Just as spotify at the beginning, hope they add this feautre. Thanks.

Comment: You are able to make a Smart playlist (in iTunes only, however) that will auto-update and you can set that be available offline.

Answer (score 4):

I've written [a short blog post](https://www.vanmil.org/how-to-automatically-download-all-apple-music-songs/) explaining how to do this.

You create a smart playlist with a single rule which checks if the `iCloud Status` equals `Apple Music`. Check the `Make Available Offline` setting for this playlist and all Apple Music songs/albums will be automatically downloaded when you add them to your library.